# JWT_Auth returning a token is required for getPayload even though one is supplied

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt

I am using the JWT-Auth package in my Laravel 5.6 project.

I have a simple test which is using the getPayload method, but it keeps returning;

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException: A token is required
```

My method is as follows so far;

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();

$token = JWTAuth::fromUser($user);
$payload = JWTAuth::getPayload($token);
```

If i do a `dd($token)` it spits out the users token correctly.

If anyone else has run into this, i would love some help.

Cheers

Comment: what happens if you call it as `$payload = JWTAuth::parseToken()->getPayload();` ?

Comment: @NimeshkaSrimal i get the following; `Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException: The token could not be parsed from the request`

Comment: How about `$payload = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->getPayload();` ?

Comment: Oh that worked perfect, my test is now running ... What the difference between parseToken and setToken?

Comment: If you wouldnt mind that would help me understand, thanks so much

Comment: I went through the source and found that when you create the token using fromUser() method, it doesn't set any value to $this->token variable. But getPayload() method checks to see if $this->token is set. That's why it failed. When you set the token before calling parseToken(), it has access to $this->token. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted. Will edit to add more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, it would work if you call it as:

`$payload = JWTAuth::setToken($token)->getPayload();`

I had a look at the source class and it looks like the reason why ;

`$payload = JWTAuth::getPayload($token);`

returns `A token is required` error is that because it looks for `$this->token` variable. But when you set it using `JWTAuth::fromUser($user);` it doesn't set any value to it.

```
public function fromUser(JWTSubject $user)
{
    return $this->fromSubject($user);
}
```

...

```
public function fromSubject(JWTSubject $subject)
{
    $payload = $this->makePayload($subject);
    return $this->manager->encode($payload)->get();
}
```

Here you can see that `fromSubject()` actually returns the payload. So the returned result of `fromUser()` should actually contain the payload you were looking for although I'm not sure about this as I'm unable to test.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm, thank you so much for helping out